# howto mix websockets and static resources under twisted

Tags: websocket, twisted

I want to use Twisted to support my website. Sometimes documents should be editable, and sometimes must be only readable. I want to use the 'websocketsite' facilities to handle the situations when documents are editable, and a regular 'site' when the document are only readable. I don't see howto handle these two type of factories under the same reactor.  Should I usage two ports and two reactors? Is there a way to handle the situation with just one reactor?

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 examples of mixing static Web, WSGI and WebSocket on top of Twisted:

- [Mixing Twisted Web and WebSocket](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_site)
- [Mixing multiple WebSocket services with Twisted Web](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/multiproto)
- [Mixing WSGI (Flask) with WebSocket](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_wsgi)

Disclosure: I am original author of [Autobahn](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython) and work for Tavendo.